# Why my program in blazor run so slow in my IDE?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, blazor

I'm using blazor - components blazor, and visual studio community like IDE.

And my program is so slow to run and build.

Is normal?

Comment: What do you call slow? How big is the solution? Have you tried profiling

Comment: @phuzi My project have 81.1MB. So slow to navigate in aplication. How can i make profiling?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66272929/17296043) can help you?